# Is there a way that i can sync the mongo document updates with Solr using mongo-connector?

Tags: mongodb, solr

I have created a solr core (solr 7.2.0) and by using mongo-connector(using [mongo-connector](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20Solr)). By using this I am able to sync the data from Mongo to Solr. And also If i create any new record that new records also getting updated in Solr.
Here is my problem:
**I am trying to update some field value(Ex: "price" from 50 to 100 ) in mongoDB but newly updated values are not reflecting in Solr using mongo-connector. please anyone help me to sync the mongo updates with Solr.**

Comment: Have you made sure to issue a commit after the update? Either through an autoCommit, or by using `--auto-commit-interval` with mongo-connector?

Comment: Yes @MatsLindh i have used "--auto-commit-interval=0"
full command 
"*mongo-connector -v -m  localhost:27017 -n dev.objTest -t http://localhost:8983/solr/objTest --auto-commit-interval=0 -d solr_doc_manager --unique-key=_id*"

Comment: What does the Solr log show for the updates? You can see the log by going to "Logging" in the admin interface and selecting INFO as the log level - it should log all requests Solr receives.